# SwiftUI View Not Updating on Real Device but Works Correctly in Simulator

Tags: swift, swiftui, timer, testflight, observableobject

I am currently working on a SwiftUI project that involves a timer functionality. The app has a list of "activities" and each activity can be started, stopped, and updated. The ViewModel class is an ObservableObject and it publishes updates to these activities. In the simulator, my views update correctly when an activity's timer is started or stopped. However, when testing on a real device (via TestFlight), the views do not update immediately.

Here is my ViewModel class:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var activities: [Activity] {
        didSet {
            currentTimes = activities.map { $0.currentTime }
        }
    }
    @Published var currentTimes: [TimeInterval]
    @Published var showingAddActivity = false
    @Published var newActivityName = ""
    
    private var store = ActivityStore()
    private var timer: Timer?

    init() {
        let loadedActivities = store.load()
        self.activities = loadedActivities
        self.currentTimes = loadedActivities.map { $0.currentTime }
        if activities.contains(where: { $0.isPlaying }) {
            startGlobalTimer()
        }
    }
    
    //... Other functions such as startActivity(), stopActivity(), loadActivities(), saveActivities(), timerTick(), startGlobalTimer(), stopGlobalTimer() ...
}
```

Each Activity is represented by a row in my view, and when the isPlaying property of an Activity changes (i.e., the timer starts or stops), the row should update to reflect this change. This works correctly in the simulator, but not on my real device.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on what might be causing this discrepancy between the simulator and a real device? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.